# Octave Jupyter Notebook xlsread error

Tags: jupyter-notebook, octave

I am receiving this error when trying to run my .m script in an Octave Jupyter Notebook on Ubuntu 16.04:

> warning: Functions for spreadsheet style I/O (.xls .xlsx .sxc .ods
>   .dbf .wk1 etc.)  are provided in the io package.  See
>   http://octave.sf.net/io/.
>
> Please read http://www.octave.org/missing.html to learn how you can
>   contribute missing functionality. warning: called from
>       **unimplemented** at line 524 column 5
>       calc_slope_per_year at line 7 column 8 error: 'xlsread' undefined near line 7 column 10 error: called from
>       calc_slope_per_year at line 7 column 8

I originally didn't have the package io installed, so I installed it, but still receive the same error.  Verified here:

> Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
>   --------------+---------+-----------------------
>             io  |  2.4.10 | /home/m/octave/io-2.4.10

Here is my kernelspec list:

```
$ jupyter kernelspec list
Available kernels:
  python3    /home/m/.local/share/jupyter/kernels/python3
  ir         /home/m/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/ir
  octave     /home/m/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/octave
  python2    /home/m/anaconda2/share/jupyter/kernels/python2
```

I have also tried to use oct2py in a Python 3 Jupyter Notebook:

```
from oct2py import octave
```

but receive the same error

> Oct2PyError: Octave evaluation error: error: 'xlsread' undefined near
>   line 7 column 10 error: called from:
>       calc_slope_per_year at line 7, column 8

Interestingly, when I ran my .m script in the Octive GUI without io package installed yet, it worked fine.  Any Suggestions?

Comment: have you tried a `pkg load io` before trying to use xlsread?

Comment: That was what I was missing, thanks @Andy! Do you know why Octave was able to run the .m script without installing or loading io?  Did I miss a blanket package install step when setting up my Jupyter Octave Notebook?

Comment: perhaps you have a .octaverc where you do `pkg load io`

Answer (score 0):

After following the advice of Andy's comment, `pkg load io` in the Octave Jupyter Notebook did the trick.

If you run the `pkg list` command, it will list the package and show whether the pkg is loaded or not:

If it is installed but not loaded, there won't be an * next to io.

> Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
>             io |  2.4.10 | /home/m/octave/io-2.4.10

If it is installed and loaded, there will be an * next to io.

> Package Name  | Version | Installation directory
>             io *|  2.4.10 | /home/m/octave/io-2.4.10

Also, if I load the io package in my Octave Jupyter notebook, it unloads it from the Octave program and visa versa.

Might be getting off topic here for a new question but is there a way to load it permanently for both instances?